# something was done and something done?

Tags: passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs, ellipsis

> The outline was then drawn in green and the centre point plotted in the centre of the circle as a red dot.

Is it necessary to add 'was' before 'plotted' to present a passive voice? I sometimes see some sentences like this one, which does not have 'be/was/were/is/are' before the verb of the past perfect tense.

Comment: It's not a matter of *necessary to add 'was' before 'plotted'*. It's okay to *"**delete**"* the second (repeated, predictable) instance of auxiliary verb ***was*** in contexts like this. But you don't *have* to - it's entirely an optional stylistic choice that has no effect on meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the word "was" before "plotted" in this example. You don't have to delete it; it is a style choice.  Deleting the word "was" is correct in formal English.

There is more redundancy that you can remove: "The centre point ... in the centre".  That is a "tautology".  You can just say "The centre of the circle [was] plotted as a red dot.